# Find the inverse function of $\log_{\sqrt{4-x^2} } \left(x^3+5x^2-x \right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the inverse function for the following function:

$$f(x) = \log_{\sqrt{4-x^2} } \left(x^3+5x^2-x \right)$$

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and what is function 3?

Comment: i was unable to make any efforts!i just didn't have the idea.and function 3 is just a name to avoid conflict with other names. @miracle173

Comment: Could you tell us the reason you think there is an inverse that can be written in closed form? Or are there other forms you would accept, such as infinite series?

Comment: The logarithm to base $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ notation can be avoided but I would be surprised if there is an inverse that can be composed of elementary functions $$\begin{array}\\
f(x) &=& \log_{\sqrt{4-x^2} } \left(x^3+5x^2-x \right)\\
&=&\frac{\log(x^3+5x^2-x)}{\log{ \sqrt{4-x^2}}} \\
&=&
2\frac{\log(x)+\log(x-\frac{-5-\sqrt{29}}{2})+\log(x-\frac{-5+\sqrt{29}}{2})}{  \log(2-x)+\log(2+x)}
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the graph, your function is not one-to-one. (The blue dashed lines are vertical asymptotes, as is the $y$ axis.)

[image: Graph of given function f(x)]

A particular $y$ value can have up to $4$ corresponding $x$ values. Therefore, the function does not have an inverse.

It would be possible to restrict the domain so that the function becomes one-to-one. These are the basic intervals you could use for a domain: $\left(-2,-\sqrt{3}\right)$, $\left(-\sqrt{3},0\right)$, $\left(\frac{-5+\sqrt{29}}{2},\sqrt{3}\right)$, and $\left(\sqrt{3},2\right)$. The largest of these is the second. Another interval that is a subset of one of these would also work.

Your function expression can be simplified in several ways, but I do not see any way to find a closed-form expression for any inverse for a restriction of your function. I doubt that any closed-form expression is possible. We could *calculate* an inverse and write non-closed-form expressions, but that is a different thing.

Comment: thanks for you answer.Can you calculate the inverse of this restricted version please?

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: As I wrote in my answer, you need to state the particular domain of restriction that you want. Do you want the one I mentioned, do you want another, or shall I just choose one?

Comment: Is the domain you mentioned above the biggest one?If so I would gladly want that :D and BTW if we just pretend this function is one-to-one can we calculate the inverse then?

Comment: @FuriousMathematician: See the edits to my answer. My previous answer was partly wrong...but no one else caught the mistakes, fortunately for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Brute force inverse.**   It is always possible to *tabulate* the function over a certain interval, for example $\left(-\sqrt{3},0\right)$ as suggested by Rory Daulton. For each argument of the inverse function as desired followed by a search in the table entry of the $y$-values and constructing the corresponding function $x$-value by interpolation. Here comes a non-optimized Pascal program snippet that does the job. The more refined the sampling (`Wide = 1000` here ) , the better the result.

```
program furious;

const
  Wide : integer = 1000;
var
  xmin,xmax : double;
  x,y : array of double;

function F(x : double) : double;
begin
  F := ln(x*sqr(x)+5*sqr(x)-x)/ln(sqrt(4-sqr(x)));
end;

function i2x(i : integer) : double;
begin
  i2x := xmin + i*(xmax-xmin)/(Wide-1);
end;

procedure table;
var
  i : integer;
  min,max : double;
begin
  xmin := -sqrt(3); xmax := 0;
  SetLength(x,Wide);
  SetLength(y,Wide);
  min := 0; max := 0;
{ Avoiding singularities }
  for i := 1 to Wide-2 do
  begin
    x[i] := i2x(i);
    y[i] := F(x[i]);
    if y[i] < min then min := y[i];
    if y[i] > max then max := y[i];
  { if i < 20 then TEST
    Writeln(y[i],' ',x[i]); }
  end;
{ Writeln(min,' < x <',max); }
end;

function inverse(w : double) : double;
var
  k,item : integer;
begin
  item := 0;
  for k := 1 to Wide-3 do
  begin
    item := k;
    if (y[k+1] <= w) and (w <= y[k]) then Break;
  end;
  k := item; { Writeln(k); }
  inverse := x[k+1]+(w-y[k+1])/(y[k]-y[k+1])*(x[k]-x[k+1]);
end;

begin
  table;
  Writeln(inverse(100));
end.
```

Output:

```
-1.71754524598803E+0000
```

**Note.**   In the world where I come from - Applied Physics -
there exist truly ugly functions (e.g. of temperature) that aim to describe material
properties, often consisting of several pieces. Finding the inverse of
such a function can only be done with the above method, as far as I know.
Insisting on closed forms simply means there that you're out of business.

Comment: This is pretty good, though slow as algorithms go. Since we know the function's formula and the derivative is not difficult, I would recommend a form of Newton-Raphson that keeps the $x$-value within the domain: something like [rtsafe](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c9-4.pdf) in *Numerical Recipes*.